# How do I permanently save lines of text over time

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Whenever I click a button I want the text in a label to be saved to a TextView and I want to keep what's already in the text view as well. Here is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saved2: UITextView!

@IBAction func sve(_ sender: Any) {
    let savedString = label.text
    let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(savedString, forKey: "key")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    let value = userDefaults.string(forKey: "key")
    saved2.text = value
}
```

How can I save a new value to the next line without resetting the textview?

Comment: Unrelated but you need to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` in your overridden `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Where's your attempt to update the text view with the text in the label?

Comment: thanks the tip!  saved2.text = value should update the textview everytime viewwillAppear is called right? value is = to userDefault which is equal to saved string. Every time I load the app in the sim it loads what the last saved label was just not any other saved label.

Comment: Right because you only save the label's current value to `UserDefaults` in the `sve` function.

Comment: @rmaddy well it works for some reason how can i keep what's currently in the textview and get the new label saved as well

Comment: @Matt I don't understand what you mean by '`how can i keep what's currently in the textview and get the new label into it`'

Comment: @George_E_2 yes sorry I didn't explain that well i want to be able to save the current label to the text view and then later on save another iteration of the label to the textview and not delete what was previously in the textview.

Comment: So you want to _append_ text to the `UITextView`?

Comment: @ George_E_2 yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```js
protocol TextStorage: class {
    var text: String { get set }
}

final class TextStorageImpl: TextStorage {

    private var storage = UserDefaults.standard
    private let key = "key"

    var text: String {
        get {
            return storage.string(forKey: key) ?? ""
        }
        set {
            var newString = text
            newString.append(newValue)
            storage.set(newString, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var saved2: UITextView!

    private let textStorage: TextStorage = TextStorageImpl()

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = label.text {
            textStorage.text = text
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        saved2.text = textStorage.text
    }
}
```